# Keep receiving a nonetype error

Tags: python, nonetype, python-3.6

I'm still super new at this. The code is supposed to continue looping until/unless I hit enter without entering a value. It goes for 2 loops, and then gives me a `NoneType` error. Frustrated. Please help. My code:

```
import random
hourly = 70
CustomerID = random.randint(100000,999999)
Customers = {}
characters = ['a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z']

def generateRecord():
    cusName = input('Enter customer name:')
    cusIncome = int(input('Enter customer annual income:'))
    consulTime = int(input('Enter Consultation time in minutes:'))
    if cusIncome <= 25000:
                     CustRate = (.4)
                     print('Rate = 40% for time over 30 minutes')
    if cusIncome > 25000:
                     CustRate = (.7)
                     print('Rate = 70% for time over 20 minutes')
    if CustRate ==.4 and consulTime< 30:
        CustRate == 0
    if CustRate==.7 and consulTime <20:
        CustRate == 0

    billingAmt = hourly*CustRate*(consulTime/60)
    CustomerID
    print('Customer ID is '+str(CustomerID))
    Customers[CustomerID] = [cusName, cusIncome, consulTime, CustRate, billingAmt]

def generateBillAmount():
    cusIncome = int(input('Enter customer annual income:'))
    consulTime = int(input('Enter Consultation time in minutes:'))
    if cusIncome <= 25000:
        CustRate = .4
        print('Rate = 40% for time over 30 minutes')
    else:
        CustRate = .7
        print('Rate = 70% for time over 20 minutes')
    if CustRate ==.4 and consulTime< 30:
        CustRate = 0
    if CustRate==.7 and consulTime <20:
        CustRate = 0
    billingAmt = int(hourly*CustRate*(consulTime/60))
    if CustRate==.4 and consulTime>30:
        billingAmt = int(hourly*CustRate*((consulTime-30)/60))
    if CustRate==.7 and consulTime>20:
        billingAmt = int(hourly*CustRate*((consulTime-20)/60))
    print('Customer total is ' +str(billingAmt)+' dollars.')

generateRecord()
for cusName in generateRecord():
    for character in cusName:
        if cusName == '\n':
            print(Customers)
            break
        else:
            generateRecord()
generateBillAmount()
```

Here's what it returns, usually:

```
Enter customer name:jake
Enter customer annual income:15000
Enter Consultation time in minutes:15
Rate = 40% for time over 30 minutes
Customer ID is 594578
Enter customer name:trix
Enter customer annual income:45000
Enter Consultation time in minutes:45
Rate = 70% for time over 20 minutes
Customer ID is 594578

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hammad/GenerateRecords.py", line 45, in <module>
    *for cusName in generateRecord():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable*
```

Comment: `generateRecord()` does not `return` anything. So by default it will be `None`.

Comment: Basically you get all that printout because you go through all of the `input` statements that are contained within `generateRecord()`. Once you get to the end of that function, you break out and `for cusName in generateRecord():` is the same as `for cusName in None:` Whatever you intended to iterate through, you need `return what_you_want` at the end of `generateRecord` function body.

Answer (score 2):

Unless specified explicitly a `return` value, python returns `None` as default. Since you are looping over the response of `generateRecord()` which is `None`; so you are getting an error. Try defining a return value for the function

Answer (score 1):

It is because `generateRecord()` does not return anything. Therefore anything created will not be saved. So by default it will be `None` which cannot be iterated over. Change the definition to the following

```
def generateRecord(Customers):
```

Add at the end of that function add

```
return Customers
```

This will then change the Customers dictionary outside the scope of the function...